# Can I call function prop from a native component?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm building a native component that implements an infinite scroll view using the technique described here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-104/

I'd like to pass a function prop to the native component that returns a React element for a given index `i`:

`<InfiniteScrollView renderRow={ (i) => <Row ... /> } />`

Is this possible? How can I call the function prop (`renderRow`) and then convert the returned component into a UIView?

Comment: I'm interested in creating such component. Have you made any progress on your project?